# C# Graph API Call Delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

Calling Graph API ME Request.

I am trying to call a delegate call using c# and a console application. Right now this is the error I received `"Code: generalException\r\nMessage: An error occurred sending the request.\r\n"`

Its a c# console trying to call graph api.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            string secretKey = <secretKey>;
            string appId = <clientID>;
            string tenantId = <tenantID>;
            string tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            List<string> scopeURL = new List<string>();
            scopeURL.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a username");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a password");
            var password = GetConsoleSecurePassword();

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(appId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopeURL);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            try
            {
                User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                            .WithUsernamePassword(username, password)
                            .GetAsync();

                var books = await graphClient.BookingBusinesses.Request().GetAsync();
                foreach (var book in books)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(book.DisplayName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static SecureString GetConsoleSecurePassword()
        {
            SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo i = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    pwd.RemoveAt(pwd.Length - 1);
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                }
                else
                {
                    pwd.AppendChar(i.KeyChar);
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            return pwd;
        }
```

I would really like to be able to call bookingBusiness, however I can't even read my User.

These are my permission for the application. What I am missing?
[image]

As asked

```
Message: An error occurred sending the request.

 ---> Microsoft.Graph.Auth.AuthenticationException: Code: generalException
Message: Unexpected exception returned from MSAL.

 ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.19.0.0.MsalServiceException:
        ErrorCode: service_not_available
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Service is unavailable to process the request
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.ExecuteWithRetryAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, HttpMethod method, ICoreLogger logger, Boolean doNotThrow, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.ExecuteWithRetryAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, HttpMethod method, ICoreLogger logger, Boolean doNotThrow, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.SendGetAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, ICoreLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.WsTrustWebRequestManager.GetMexDocumentAsync(String federationMetadataUrl, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.PerformWsTrustMexExchangeAsync(String federationMetadataUrl, String cloudAudienceUrn, UserAuthType userAuthType, String username, SecureString password)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.UsernamePasswordRequest.FetchAssertionFromWsTrustAsync()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.UsernamePasswordRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordParameters usernamePasswordParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.UsernamePasswordProvider.GetNewAccessTokenAsync(AuthenticationProviderOption msalAuthProviderOption)
        StatusCode: 500
        ResponseBody: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><s:Value xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">s:Receiver</s:Value>
        Headers: Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2020 12:48:52 GMT

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.UsernamePasswordProvider.GetNewAccessTokenAsync(AuthenticationProviderOption msalAuthProviderOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.UsernamePasswordProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
   at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.UserRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ConsoleGraph.Program.ClientDelegateApp(String clientId, String tenantId, String secretKey, List`1 scopes) in D:\src\ConsoleGraph\ConsoleGraph\Program.cs:line 61
```

Comment: hi,I tested your code, it's no problem, but the wrong password will appear the same error as you, please check it..

Comment: The issue here is you are not passing the client_secret here to the /token endpoint. If you don't want to pass the secret you need to make the Application as public client. You can change the application to public client by going to App registration-->{Your App}-->Authentication-->Default Client type-->Change to 'yes'

Comment: Let me know if that resolves your issue :)-

Comment: I change the the default client type to yes, but I still received a null exception.

Comment: Can you share the whole error response? Did it atleast work for /me endpoint? Try commenting the books call and forloop and see. Also check if you have created a client secret for it.

Comment: The issues occurs when calling User me = await graphclient.Me.Request().WithUsernamePassword(username,password).getAsync(); The error is 'ex.Message' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: I was able to use your code and get my profile. Don't use ex.Message. Use just 'ex' and print the whole error and share please.

Comment: Update my question to include the full stack error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222180/discussion-between-shiva-msft-identity-and-jseb).

Comment: Hi @Jseb have you find a way to resolve authentication in console app ?